# Is there is any way to programatically clear the console of Xcode during scene change/ function call?

Tags: ios, console, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing an `iOS` app using `cocos2d`.

**My question is:**

> Is there is any way to programatically clear the console of Xcode during scene change or function call?

I found several duplicates of my posts in stack overflow also, but nothing gave me a correct solution.

**What I do not need:**

- Please do not post any method to change settings on Xcode's preferences.
- Please do not post any keyboard methods (shortcuts).

**What I will appreciate:**

- A good programmatical method to clear the Xcode console, that can be used inside any cocos2d application code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This begs the question: why???

The best you can do is:

```
NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
```

A good way is to just copy&paste the contents of the log into a text editor, and do so before/after changing scenes and perhaps edit/crop the log in the text editor.